# How to solve correctly inside a DO loop and then plot

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Here is the corresponding code

First the equations setup

```
Vcl[x_, y_, z_] := (-G*(Mcl/a))/Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/a^2 + c^2];
V[x_, y_, z_] := Vcl[x, y, z] + 1/2*(κ2 - 4*ω^2)*x^2 + 1/2*v2*z^2;

G = 1;
Mcl = 2.2; a = 0.182; c = 1;
ω = 1; κ2 = 1.8; v2 = 7.6;
cl = -3.264444506;
ch = 0.1;
E0 = cl*(1 - ch);
```

Then the DO loop with the `Solve`

```
data = {};
Do[
  Vx = V[x, 0, z0];
  sol = Solve[Vx == E0 && -1.01 < x < 1.01,x];
  xmin = x /. sol[[1]];
  xmax = x /. sol[[2]];
  AppendTo[data, {xmin, xmax, z0}],
  {z0, 0, 0.6, 0.001}
  ]
```

And finally the plot

```
neg = data[[All, {1, 3}]];
pos = data[[All, {2, 3}]];
L1 = ListPlot[neg, Joined -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.003]}];
L2 = ListPlot[pos, Joined -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.003]}]; 
L0 = Show[{L1, L2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.6}}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which produces this
[image]

The plot has several issues: (i) it should be a continuous line from -1 to 1, while we observe a gap near 0 and also it never reaches +1, (ii) the lower horizontal line it should not be there; probably `Joined` joins two extreme points. I suspect, that both issues are related to the `Solve` inside the DO loop. There z0 belongs to the interval [0, 0.6] but the equation does not have solutions for all these values. The `data` list should somehow store only the correct solutions and reject the cases where there are no solutions at all.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some warnings when solving your equation in the `Do` loop. You'd better correct the code. By the way, the solutions to your equations contains complex numbers, so the condition `-1.01 < x < 1.01` might give you the void set.

Comment: @Kuba I think that the flood of error messages is because for some values of z0 there are no solutions. This is exactly what I want to know; how to get reject these cases from the list. The `Solve` syntax is corrected. BTW, thanks for the shorter version of `neg`!

Comment: @Z-Y.L I think that the warnings when solving the equations in the `Do` loop are mainly because there are no solutions for every value of z0;

Comment: @Kuba So is there no solution to the problem at all?

Comment: @Kuba Perhaps `data = Flatten[
   Do[Vx = V[x, 0, z0]; sol = Solve[Vx == E0 && -1.01 < x < 1.01, x]; 
      If[Length@sol > 0, Sow[Join[sol[[;; 2, 1, 2]], {z0}]]];, {z0, 
       0, .6, .001}] // Reap // Last, 1];` is better and combined with `Off[Solve::ratnz];` at the top there are no warnings any more. But again the plot is not correct.

Comment: @Kuba There are two issues with the plot: (i) it is not continuous; there is a gap near 0 and (ii) at the right part near +1 the last point joins incorrectly back near -1.

Comment: Why not use `ContourPlot[V[x, 0, z0] == E0, {x, -2, 2}, {z0, 0, 0.6}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods I'm really speechless, one line solution! Please make a quick answer so as to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid the problem altogether by using `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[V[x, 0, z0] == E0, {x, -2, 2}, {z0, 0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using a finer grid in the loop (e.g. 0.0001) helps to reduce the gap in the middle.

If we do not join the data points and give different colors to your `neg` and `pos` lists, we see that something strange happens for small $z_0$: Your equation has 4 solutions (two negative, two positive), so just using the first or the second argument wont pick the smallest or largest.

```
 neg = data[[All, {1, 3}]];
 pos = data[[All, {2, 3}]];
 L1 = ListPlot[neg, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.002]}];
 L2 = ListPlot[pos, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.002]}];
 L0 = Show[{L1, L2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 0.6}}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

We can also see this if we plot $V$ and $E_0$ together for different $z_0$ (just at the beginning you can see it)

```
 Export["~/test.gif", Table[Plot[{V[x, 0, z0], E0}, {x, -1.01, 1.01}, PlotRange -> {-4.5, -1.5}, Frame -> True], {z0, 0.2, 0.55, 0.01}], "GIF"]
```

[image]

If you want `xmin` and `xmax` you will always have a gap close to +/- 1, but you can do it like this:

```
 data = {};
 Do[Vx = V[x, 0, z0];
    sol = Solve[Vx == E0 && -1.01 < x < 1.01, x];
    xmin = x /. First@sol;
    xmax = x /. Last@sol;
    AppendTo[data, {xmin, xmax, z0}], {z0, 0.25, 0.55, 0.0001}]
```

[image]

If you want all real solutions between -1.01 and 1.01 you can do this:

```
data = {};
Do[Vx = V[x, 0, z0];
  sol = Solve[Vx == E0 && -1.01 < x < 1.01, x];
  allx = {x, z0} /. sol;
  If[NumberQ[First@Flatten@allx],
     AppendTo[data, Flatten[{allx}, 1]]], 
{z0, 0.25, 0.55, 0.0001}]
ListPlot[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

where it seems a little hacky with all the `Flatten` and I am checking if there is a solution before I append it to the list, but it works and you get (maybe) what you want (where using a finer grid for `z0` reduces the gap even more):

[image]

Comment: This would be improved if you use `Reap/Sow` instead of `AppendTo`

Comment: sure, I just didn't want to obfuscate the important changes, that help to solve the main problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 'cheat':

```
p1 = Plot3D[V[x, 0, z], {x, -1.01, 1.01}, {z, 0, 0.6}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{E0}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

You can then extract the desired mesh points from the object:

```
lns = Cases[p1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
gr = Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
   Line[(p1[[1, 1]][[lns[[2]]]])[[All, {1, 2}]]]}, Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: See above a much simpler solution by @Simon Woods!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z thank you...should have thought of that...and should have read the comments...

Comment: @ubpdqn at least you're keeping it funky :)

Comment: Ingenuous yet horribly convoluted. I like it! +1